# Use of "nach" with abbiegen or einbiegen

Tags: usage

Welcher Satz stimmt? Oder sagt man beides?

> "Biegen Sie *nach* rechts ab/ein."

> "Biegen Sie rechts ab/ein."

Ist **"nach"** obligatorisch?

Answer (score 4):

Man sagt beides, wobei *einbiegen* sich in meinen Ohren irgendwie schräg anhört, was an regionalen Unterschieden liegen mag. Duden listet [*einbiegen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einbiegen) ohne Hinweis auf regionale Besonderheiten.

Was *nach* angeht, liegt der Unterschied darin, ob es sich um eine Richtungs- oder eine Ortsangabe handelt.

> Biegen Sie **nach** rechts ab.

gibt die Richtung an.

Genauso gut kann aber jemand auf eine Straße oder Einfahrt hinweisen und sagen:

> Biegen Sie (dort/hier) rechts ab.

*Rechts* ist dann eine Ortsangabe und die Richtung ist schon klar inbegriffen.

Comment: Bei Autobahnkreuzen mit kreuzungsfreiem Verkehr hat man oft eine Spur, die sich gabelt, und erst geht es für die, die rechts weiterwollen rechts ab, dann kommen die, die von rechts kommen auf die Spur, dann kommt eine Spur die schlaufenförmig im Ergebnis nach links führt, aber auch recht abbiegt. Daher würde ich in einem Fahrschulauto, das die ersten 2 Mündungen passiert hat, "Biegen Sie rechts ab" durchaus als Hinweis verstehen, dass wir nach links wollen, aber vor allen Aufspaltungen würde ich "Biegen Sie nach links ab" verstehen, als an der 3. Mündung. Dort/hier sind Ortsangb., re. nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe beide Varianten, mit und ohne "nach", gesehen, daher würde ich davon ausgehen, dass man in der Alltagssprache beides verwenden kann und "nach" nicht verpflichtend ist.

Die Straßenverkehrsordnungen in [Deutschland](https://www.stvo.de/strassenverkehrsordnung/97-9-abbiegen-wenden-und-rueckwaertsfahren), [Österreich](https://www.jusline.at/gesetz/stvo/paragraf/38) und der [Schweiz](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1979/1961_1961_1961/de) verwenden durchweg "nach". Falls es also ein offizieller Text sein soll, würde ich mich daran halten.

Comment: Glaubst Du, Gesetzestexte werden generell mit sprachlicher Sorgfalt erstellt?

Comment: Generell ja, und zwar um Missverständnissen vorzubeugen. Deswegen sind diese Texte ja auch so kompliziert: So gut wie jedes Wort hat eine feste Bedeutung und muss klar definiert sein bzw. möglichst wenig Interpretationsspielraum lassen. Beim hier vorliegenden Thema ("nach") kann man sich allerdings streiten, zugegeben :)